# How to prevent Chrome rect.width knockout property binding console error?

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, knockout.js, console.log

I'm using knockout to render data-bound templates, and it works great. But I'm having a problem specifically binding `rect.width` in an SVG graphic:

```
<svg class="progress-bar">
  <rect class="background" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
  <rect class="completed" x="0" y="2%" height="96%" width="{{bindingExpression}}%"></rect>
</svg>
```

This actually works fine in the browser, but in Chrome it shows a console error:

> knockout-3.4.2.debug.js Error:  attribute width: Expected length, "{{bindingExpression}}".

In Firefox, there is no console error.

Functionally, it works fine, but the console error is annoying, alarming for testers, and obscures other, more real issues, so I'd really like to prevent or suppress it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work and not throw a console error if I set the width using the attr binding:

```
<svg class="progress-bar">
  <rect class="background" height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
  <rect class="completed" x="0" y="2%" height="96%" width="0" data-bind="attr:{width: bindingExpression.toString() + '%'}"></rect>
</svg>
```